# Does the dispatcher LUIS app can be used as part of the another dispatcher LUIS model?

Tags: botframework, dispatcher, azure-language-understanding

I wanted to ask about the possibility of creasing Disptacher Luis models using CLI by using an already existing dispatcher.
Did you have any problems with that?

Is there enough to add it according to a lower pattern or maybe it's done differently?

```
dispatch add -t luis -i "<app-id-for-weather-app>" -n "<name-of-weather-app>" -v <app-version-number> -k "<your-luis-authoring-key>" --intentName l_Weather
```

and finally, how to update such an NLU model when we have to manage two LUIS dispatchers?

Thank you for all suggestions and advice

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to add apps to dispatch models, you can find a complete documentation about dispatch models in the following link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already have seen this article before. When it comes to answers: Does the dispatcher LUIS app can be used as part of another dispatcher LUIS model? - Yes it can. We simply need to add the dispatcher app as a regular LUIS application to the main dispatcher. How to update such an NLU model when we have to manage two LUIS dispatchers? - run dispatch refresh command in node.js cmd starting from the lowest apps in NLU hierarchy